# Unable to redirect with transitionTo to nested resource route

Tags: ember.js

Update: I upgraded to rc3 and the issue persists. I have found that the second linkTo click is successful.

Ember.js v1.0.0-rc.3

My router with nested resources, for context:

```
App.Router.map(function(match) {
    this.resource('items', function() {
        this.resource('item', { path: ':item_id' }, function() {
            this.resource('images', function() {
                this.resource('image', { path: ':image_id' });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

I would like '/items' to redirect to the first item: '/items/1'

```
App.ItemsRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return App.Item.find({});
    },
    redirect: function() {
        var item = this.modelFor('items').get('firstObject');
        this.transitionTo('item', item);
    }
});
```

The problem: Hitting /items errors out with:

```
Error: assertion failed: Cannot call get with 'id' on an undefined object.
```

Note: My ItemIndexRoute is also redirecting in order to display the first image in its outlet:

```
App.ItemIndexRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return App.Item.find(params.item_id);
    },
    redirect: function(params) {
        var image = App.Image.find(params.item_id).get('firstObject');
        this.transitionTo('images');
    }
});
```

If I remove the redirect on ItemIndexRoute then I get the following at /items instead:

WARNING: The immediate parent route ('a') did not render into the main outlet and the        default 'into' option ('p') may not be expected
ember.js:349Transitioned into 'items.item.index'